# Correctly generate a form builder object while discarding the HTML without a deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, form-for

I have a partial which generates a div with some form fields in it.  It uses the form builder variable "f" which is provided as input to correctly name the fields in the parameter has (fields are actually nested attributes, so the name is like "[author][book][0][title]").

I want to use that same partial when receiving an AJAX call to regenerate the div based on new user information.  I am currently using `<% form_for ... |f| %>` in my erb file, but that generates a warning that "<% %>" is deprecated.

My erb file looks like the following:

```
<% if f.nil? %>
  <% form_for(@author, :id => :coupon_form) do |f| %>
    <%= render "books_detail1", :f => f %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= render "books_detail1", :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

So what is the correct way to create a form builder context while discarding the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to use **fields_for**.  It generates the same form builder object without the html.  I lost track of this in it's use for sub-forms, but it's really the same thing.